# How can I create two pagination in a single page with two different queries using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just started to learn PHP this week, and I'd search for possible solution on this but I can make it right. While I sucessfully created a pagination that sorts queries into alphabetical order, I wasn't successful in creating a numerical pagination, in which it will limit the number of queries to be displayed. Also, I wasn't able to combined these two types of pagination with two different queries, one for A-Z sorting, and one for the number of queries to be displayed in a single page. 
Here's my code

```
    `<?php
        include 'includes/connection.php';

        $character = '';
        $characters = '';



        if (isset($_GET['character']))
        {
            $character = $_GET['character'];
               $character = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $character);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM drivers_info WHERE last_name LIKE '$character%' ORDER BY last_name";
       }
        else{

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM drivers_info ORDER BY rfid ";
            $pageno = 1 
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    <body>
            <br /><br />
            <br /> <br />
```

Here's the code to create an alphabetical pagination

```
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <div align="center">
                 <?php
                 $character = range('A', 'Z'); 
                 echo '<ul class="pagination">';
                 foreach($character as $alphabet)
                 {
                     echo '<li><a href = "users.php?character='.$alphabet.'">'.$alphabet.'</a></li>';
                 }
                 echo '</ul>';
                 ?>
                 </div>
          <?php
```

Here's the code for displaying the queries alphabetically

```
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            ?> 
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["rfid"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["middle_name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["gender"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["height"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["weight"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["contact_no"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["license_type"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["license_no"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["expiration"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["nationality"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["eyes_color"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["blood_type"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                    }
            }



</body>
```

If you had any code or idea on it, would you mind sharing it with me? Thank you so much, I needed this to accomplish my school project.

```
            `
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is best reference code for understanding pagination logic

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "New";
$db = "booksgood";

// open connection
$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");

// select database
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 

// how many rows to show per page
$rowsPerPage = 10;

// by default we show first page
$page_num = 1;

// if $_GET['page'] defined, use it as page number, $_GET gets the page number out of the url
//set by the $page_pagination below
if(isset($_GET['page'])){$page_num = $_GET['page'];}

//the point to start for the limit query
$offset = $page_num; 

// Zero is an incorrect page, so switch the zero with 1, mainly because it will cause an error with the SQL
if($page_num == 0) {$page_num = 1;}

// counting the offset
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookdata where titles like 's%' order by titles LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage ";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// how many rows we have in database
$sql2  = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS numrows FROM bookdata where titles like 's%'";
$res2  = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$row2  = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
$numrows = $row2['numrows'];

// print the random numbers
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
//Echo out your table contents here.

echo $row[1].'<BR>';
echo $row[2].'<BR>';
echo '<BR>';
}

// how many pages we have when using paging?
$numofpages = ceil($numrows/$rowsPerPage);

// print the link to access each page
$self = "/paging3.php?";

if ($numofpages > '1' ) {

            $range =15; //set this to what ever range you want to show in the pagination link
            $range_min = ($range % 2 == 0) ? ($range / 2) - 1 : ($range - 1) / 2;
            $range_max = ($range % 2 == 0) ? $range_min + 1 : $range_min;
            $page_min = $page_num- $range_min;
            $page_max = $page_num+ $range_max;

            $page_min = ($page_min < 1) ? 1 : $page_min;
            $page_max = ($page_max < ($page_min + $range - 1)) ? $page_min + $range - 1 : $page_max;
            if ($page_max > $numofpages) {
                $page_min = ($page_min > 1) ? $numofpages - $range + 1 : 1;
                $page_max = $numofpages;
            }

            $page_min = ($page_min < 1) ? 1 : $page_min;

            //$page_content .= '<p class="menuPage">';

            if ( ($page_num > ($range - $range_min)) && ($numofpages > $range) ) {
                $page_pagination .= '<a class="num"  title="First" href="'.$self.'page=1">&lt;</a> ';
            }

            if ($page_num != 1) {
                $page_pagination .= '<a class="num" href="'.$self.'page='.($page_num-1). '">Previous</a> ';
            }

            for ($i = $page_min;$i <= $page_max;$i++) {
                if ($i == $page_num)
                $page_pagination .= '<span class="num"><strong>' . $i . '</strong></span> ';
                else
                $page_pagination.= '<a class="num" href="'.$self.'page='.$i. '">'.$i.'</a> ';
            }

            if ($page_num < $numofpages) {
                $page_pagination.= ' <a class="num" href="'.$self.'page='.($page_num + 1) . '">Next</a>';
            }


            if (($page_num< ($numofpages - $range_max)) && ($numofpages > $range)) {
                $page_pagination .= ' <a class="num" title="Last" href="'.$self.'page='.$numofpages. '">&gt;</a> ';
            }

            //$page['PAGINATION'] ='<p id="pagination">'.$page_pagination.'</p>';
        }//end if more than 1 page 

echo $page_pagination.'<BR><BR>';

echo 'Number of results - '.$numrows ;
echo ' and Number of pages   - '.$numofpages.'<BR><BR>';

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($res);

// and close the database connection
mysql_close($con); 

?>
```

here is reference code [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1673528)

Comment: Wow, thank you for this. But I have a question, what if I add another pagination with different query on this code, how will the code look like?

Comment: Try to understand this code for logic and apply your own logic to add different type of query's and pagination ....I give you code bcz understand logic ...now it's depend on you how to use logic and create different type of pagination....so work on with your own logic and gain your skill....In any case you can't understand something and can't get it then i'll help you but first try by your side.....

Comment: Well, I tried your code and it works. Thanks, but unfortunately I was stuck on adding another pagination because I don't understand how  this line of code works: 
<a class="num"  title="First" href="'.$self.'page=1">&lt;</a> , does page returns an int value of 1 when called by the _GET function?

Comment: $self is page like **index.php?** <-- this is $self work like that....means <a class="num" title="First" href="index.php?page=1">&lt;</a> ....that means your pagination work on index.php....in that case whatever page you want paginate just remove $self and write page name you want to paginate....